# deploy contract on privavte blockchain using truffle

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, blockchain

I setup a private blockchain on local using geth.What I did :

1. create genesis.json
2. geth init
3. geth attach
4. create account , unlock account and mining start
5. truffle init, write contract, migrations and update truffle.js

`module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
    }
  }
};`

when I try to migrate the contract I am getting the following error :

```
Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)
```

using this command to start a node with geth :

```
geth --port 3000 --networkid 58342 --nodiscover --datadir="privchain" --maxpeers=0 autodag --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --ipcapi "eth,net,web3"
```

This is my genesis.json file :

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 58342,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000033",
  "timestamp": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
  "difficulty": "0x100",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
  "alloc": {}
}
```

Comment: According to your truffle configuration, there should be an evm-process (for example, `testrpc` or `ganache`) running on your machine and listening on port 8545.

Comment: @goodvibration, want to deploy contract on private net , so please suggest if I need to update the truffle.js

Comment: is your geth node correctly opening an RPC interface at `http://localhost:8545`? and have you specified any `--rpccorsdomain` arguments whilst starting geth?

Comment: I used this command to start node with geth : geth --port 3000 --networkid 58342 --nodiscover --datadir="privchain" --maxpeers=0 autodag --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --ipcapi "eth,net,web3"

Comment: I think you should change the port in truffle.js to match your geth port

Comment: didn't get you ! I have port 8545 in truffle.js port and geth port. do want I just change the port i truffle.js from 8545 to 8546

Comment: Make sure no other application is using port 8545. Does some error appear when you launch geth? You can try adding `--verbosity 4` to geth command line to see more logs. Also you can try removing `--rpcaddr 127.0.0.1` and let geth figure it out.

Comment: @Ismael, Not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, have a look to the Geth output. It should says something like:

```
HTTP port opened on localhost:8545
```

If it said that and you are not able to connect, you can try all of this:

1. Try to access using your web brownser (I tried with Chrome). If its works you will see your page in white. Sometimes it throws a message 
   such as "invalid host". In that case you should add --rpcvhosts="*" to let any host to connect to your host.
2. Try to connect using:

   telnet [ipaddress] [port]

Aside from the previously metioned, try to go first for a simply approach. If I were you I would try first:

```
geth --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --ipcapi "eth,net,web3"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting up your private blockchain on windows, then install the testrpc client using the following command in cmd

> npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc

Then migrate your contract it should work.[image]

Comment: Better yet, `npm install -g ganache-cli`. See [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli).